# Processing Dynamically Created Children and Siblings' Children

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've been editing and looking at this for so long I'm failing to find a seemingly easy solution.

An element (and its sibling) will have any number of different (dynamic) results, which I would like to display in an HTML table, one row for each cd-file pair. Initially thinking I could avoid for-each loops (which seem to return the same results anyway), I need a [better] way to refer to the children. The source below is similar in structure with which I'm working.

For example, some "cd"s and "file"s will have more elements such as price, some might have no information.

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.test2.xsl"?>
    <catalog>
      <rock>
        <album>
          <cd>
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
          </cd>
          <file>
            <store>Apple</store>
            <size>3823</size>
          </file>
        </album>
        <album>
          <cd>
            <title>Hide your heart</title>
            <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
          </cd>
          <file>
            <store>Amazon</store>
            <size>2123</size>
          </file>
        </album>
      </rock>
    </catalog>
```

XSLT

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html> 
    <body>
      <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
      <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
          <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
          <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
          <th style="text-align:left">Store</th>
          <th style="text-align:left">Size</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="album">
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="cd"/>  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="file"/>
      </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cd">
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </td>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="file">
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </td>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Results

```
    <table border="1">
      <tbody>
        <tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
          <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
          <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
          <th style="text-align:left">Store</th>
          <th style="text-align:left">Size</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Empire Burlesque
            Bob Dylan
            </td>
            <td>
              Apple
              3823
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Hide your heart
            Bonnie Tyler
          </td>
          <td>
            Amazon
            2123
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

[Result View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imXPJ.png)

Now, I think I see what is happening. From my interpretation, in the XSLT file, under the "cd" and "file" templates, `select="."` is returning all the children inside the `<td>`. I need a way for each to have a `<td>`. I've tried such things as call-template for each "cd" and "file," as well as for-each within the "cd" and "file" templates. Note that I also need to dynamically build the `<th>` elements, for now they're created manually for testing purposes. Any suggestions?

Comment: We need a better definition of "dynamically". For example, you could say you want a  column for every leaf node with a text value. However, I don't see a way you can avoid hardcoding which elements produce a row.

Comment: I'm referring to dynamic as opposed to static. The [number of] columns will be dynamically created, depending on what is returned from an API call. There will be 0 or more children, in this case leaves, which may or may not contain any text, with possibly different node names in different order (each of which should have a column in the table).

Comment: It's not enough to say what will change. You need to tell us what will not - so that we can use it to create a structure for the output table. If there are no constrains, then the task is impossible.

Comment: There will be 0 to 23 leaves (columns) which will have no spaces and no children, although some of the text will contain spaces and slashes (directory paths). Optional attributes may be added later, for instance to specify a link to an image to display instead of the text. Realistically, only 4 or 5 leaves will be used, although it is possible to change which will be returned in a configuration file (i.e. the number of columns is constant unless there is a change). There will also be sub-tables, if you will, which will display perhaps when hovering over a table cell in a certain column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an educated guess (it is not exactly clear what your expected output looks like, and what aspects of the input file are variable), I think you want the following.

There is no need to explicitly apply templates to the `cd` and `title` elements, just `apply-templates` in a general fashion. Also, your stylesheet is currently missing templates for `store`, `size` etcetera. As far as I understand, those are the element whose content should go inside `td` elements in the HTML output, so you need to match them with templates, even if those templates are rather general.

If you do not know the names of the table headers `th` beforehand and if there is a variable number of leaf elements that are grandchildren of `album`, here is a more "dynamic" solution:

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
        encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
                        <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(catalog/rock/album/*/*/name())">
                            <th style="text-align:left">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </th>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="album">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="album/*/*">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML Output**

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "XSLT-compat">
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
            <th style="text-align:left">title</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">artist</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">store</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">size</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Empire Burlesque</td>
            <td>Bob Dylan</td>
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>3823</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Hide your heart</td>
            <td>Bonnie Tyler</td>
            <td>Amazon</td>
            <td>2123</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Rendered HTML**

> [image]

Try this solution online [here](http://xsltransform.net/jz1PuPS/1).

Comment: Thank you for your solution and quick response. I didn't want to start my question with "I'm new to XSLT" but this is my first, after attempting your solution I'm just now realizing that modern web browsers still use XSLT 1.0! Even so, I'm still confident this is the best answer and luckily my application is using XSLT 2.0. The link to [link](http://xsltransform.net) was also useful, I was unaware of such a website. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm guessing correctly, you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <html> 
        <body>
            <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/album[1]" mode="header"/>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="album">
    <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>  
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[text()]" mode="header">
    <th>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    </th>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[text()]">
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This create a row for every `album`, and a column for every leaf node with a text node.

Note that this assumes that your input is regular - i.e. that every album has the same properties, in the same order, and none of them is empty.

Comment: I haven't tested this but it looks like a good start for XSLT 1.0. The problem is, in my case, albums may have different properties, be in random order and there could be empty results.

Comment: Then neither this nor the accepted answer will work for you.

Comment: How so? The accepted answer was suitable for my problem at hand, and gave me further insight since I'm new to this very frustrating yet potentially very useful technology :)

Comment: Just reorder the properties of one album and see for yourself.

Comment: @MasterWill It is true that my answer has the same drawbacks as this one. I am glad you found my answer useful, but Michael's answer is equally good, if not better than mine. If _"albums may have different properties, be in random order and there could be empty results."_ then you did not explain yet a part of the desired behaviour; e.g. what exactly should happen if relevant elements are empty.

Comment: Perhaps the accepted answer was premature. I still need to do some testing and modifications (I'm also new to Stack Overflow).

Comment: I am still not clear on your requirements. XML is *very* flexible, and it's virtually impossible to have an XSLT that will fit all possible variations, with no constrains. Mathias' solution assumes all properties are grandchildren of `album`. My solution assumes properties are any text nodes descendants of `album` (at any level). Both assume a fixed structure of the `album` subtree. You can use different constrains, provided you formulate them clearly.